# Why doesn't 'str' have an attribute 'name' (PyCharm 2020.3.2 Python 3.9)

Tags: python, discord.py, python-3.9

I have made a fake hack command (totally by myself) but when I type the command in the chat, an error shows up saying that `str` doesn't have attribute `member.name`

Code:

```
@commands.command()
    async def hack(self, ctx, member):
        random_id = [
            "20390940",
            "20930948",
            "09479398",
            "03984988",
            "94883099",
            "98477490",
            "37729902",
            "98765421",
            "93893893",
            "08589498",
            "88489920",
            "84990201",
            "94789435",
            "98839897",
            "49732974",
            "97398394",
            "80489033",
            "98479883",
            "97878820",
            "08839004",
            "98308934"
        ]

        async def f():
            while True:
                await ctx.send('Test')

        await ctx.send(f" Hacking {member.name}") #Here is the error
        task = asyncio.create_task(f())
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await ctx.send("❌ Firewall blocking access")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await ctx.send("✔ Firewall hacked")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await ctx.send(f" Apple Account password is {random_id}")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await ctx.send(f"〽 Credit Card ID is {random_id}")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await ctx.send(f" Discord ID is {ranid}")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await ctx.send(" Covering all traces")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await ctx.send(" Destroying browser memory")
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await ctx.send(f"✔ Finished hacking {member.name}") #Here is also the error
        task.cancel()
```

Comment: Because you pass `str` argument while function expect [`Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#member).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use converters for passing arguments. Right now, `member` parameter is a string value, that's why you're getting an `AttributeError`. You have to convert string to [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member) object. You can simply do:

```py
@commands.command()
async def hack(self, ctx, member: discord.Member):
    ...
```